# Is there a CSS/JQuery snippet for vertical menus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, templates

I'm looking for something very similar to Facebook's left menu.

- Clean and elegant
- Horizontal Bar like, with highlight when it's selected

Comment: I think it is a basic list with the list-style set to none and extra styling applied to the text. The appropriate items is highlighted during page load. I haven't even looked at the source code though - the last time I did that I became totally kaboggled (confused due to it being encrypted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a list menu and have included up to 3 tiers. in the hover styling just change the background color and teak to your specifications. This is what I use to program joomla's drop down menu. When you put it in a div. Test here http://jsfiddle.net/DnNye/3/ it still needs some tweaking to fully work but is a start.

---

### HTML

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>Home
            <ul>
                <li>Test1
                    <ul>
                        <li>Test1</li>
                        <li>Test2</li>
                        <li>Test3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Test2</li>
                <li>Test3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>About</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

### CSS

```
#navigation {width:150px; font-size:12px;}
#navigation ul {margin:0px; padding:0px; background-color:#666;}
#navigation ul li {
    height:25px;
    line-height:25px;
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:10px;
    color:#FFF;
    border-top:#fff solid;
    border-bottom:#fff solid;
    border-width:1px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#navigation ul li:hover {background-color:#F90; position:relative;}

#navigation ul ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:75px;
    top:5px;
    border:#fff solid;
    border-width:1px;
    background-color:#999;
}
#navigation ul li:hover ul {display:block;}
#navigation ul ul li {border:none; width:150px; float:left; display:inline;}
#navigation ul ul li:hover {text-decoration:underline; border:none;}
#navigation li:hover ul li ul {display:none;}
#navigation ul > ul > ul ul li ul {left:110px; background-color:#0099CC;}
#navigation ul > ul ul li:hover ul {display:block;}
```

---

### JAVASCRIPT For some Internet Explorers

```
// drop down list functionality for Internet Explore
// IE does not support the :hover in anything but links
// just need to duplacate the navigation in css and include .sfHover in place of :hover ex: #navigation ul ul li:hover becomes #navigation ul ul li:hover, navigation ul ul li.sfHover
sfHover = function() {
    var sfEls = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("LI");
    for (var i = 0; i < sfEls.length; i++) {
        sfEls[i].onmouseover = function() {
            this.className += " sfhover";
        };
        sfEls[i].onmouseout = function() {
            this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp(" sfhover\\b"), "");
        };
    }
};
if (window.attachEvent) { window.attachEvent("onload", sfHover); }
```